# Copying one part of a string to another in C

Tags: c, strstr, strncpy, ptrdiff-t

I have problems trying to copy one part of a string into a another. Given these two char pointers:

```
line points at string cointaining: "helmutDownforce:1234:44:yes"
username points at: NULL
```

Here's my function that takes these pointers as input:

```
char* findUsername(char* line, char* username){
    char* ptr = strstr(line, ":");
    ptrdiff_t index = ptr - line;
    strncpy(username, line, index);

    return username;
}
```

I get segmentation fault during strncpy. How come? The result I want is the function to return a pointer to a string containing helmutDownforce.

Comment: Are you passing a `NULL`-pointer to `strncpy()`?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Post calling code to `findUsername()`.

Answer (score 2):

This function allocates and returns a new string, so to avoid a memory leak the calling function must be responsible for eventually freeing it.  If there is no separator colon in the line it will return `NULL`.

```
char* findUsername(char* line){
    char* ptr = strchr(line, ':');
    /* check to make sure colon is there */
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    int length = ptr - line;
    char *username = malloc(length+1);

    /* make sure allocation succeeded */
    if (username == NULL) return NULL;

    memcpy(username, line, length);
    username[length] = '\0';
    return username;
}
```

Comment: Curious: why use type `int` in `int length = ptr - line;` instead of OP's `ptrdiff_t` or `size_t`, (the type received by `malloc()`?

Answer (score 1):

According to [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) of `strncpy`:

```
the destination string dest must be large enough to receive the copy
```

So you must allocate some memory first with `malloc` for `username` before calling `strncpy`.